# How do I display Json API data in html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm quite good with html and css but absolutely no experience using javascript.

I want to display the date received from this API into an html page

http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/routes.json?token=PutHereYourToken

This is how I'm trying without any success until now.

```js
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('https://api.travelpayouts.com/data/routes.json?token=mytoken').then(function(data) {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); 

    result.innerText = data.result; 
}, function(status) { 
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: @sloane Once you've actually shown some effort. It's our job to help once you've shown that you've actually tried it yourself first. You haven't done that here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, let me 3 min to edit my question, then maybe you will figure out that I tried. It's not like I come and ask without having tried since 2 hours by myself..)

Comment: @sloane You'd be surprised, people do it all the time. And if you tried, show your work. We can't know what you haven't shown. In the future, please show your efforts from the start so it doesn't seem like you're asking for an answer without already having tried yourself.

Comment: @Carcigenicate there you go. but until now I didn't achieve to diplay anything on that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is Using [Jquery](https://jquery.com)

I suggest that you learn a bit more about [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Edit: I have updated my answer to fit your case. Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9Loxtb0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=9Loxtb0t)

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/routes.json?token=PutHereYourToken",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
               $('#result').html(res)
            }
        });

})

</script>
```

Do not forget to include jQuery and the javascript code in the head section of your html.

Comment: Note, JQuery isn't required to use AJAX, but it does simplify its use a bit.

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you please accept the answer then?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example that does not use jQuery

```
// Callback to run when data is ready
function reqListener() {
  // Parse the JSON text to an object so we can get just one property
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  // Append that value to the DOM.
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = data.body;
}

// Create a new ajax requst
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Fire callback on load event
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
// Create the connection to our API
oReq.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
// Fire the request
oReq.send();
```

Learn more about ajax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and see this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h7bq46z/)